# SSIS - OLE DB Destination - Setting Target Table With Variable

Tags: variables, ssis, oledb

I am pulling data from a single table on a source system but the target table depends on the target table name listed in my view:

Source Table Schema:

```
 Name
 Date
 Department
 Job
 TargetTable
```

A target table will have the following schema:

```
 Name
 Date
 Department
 Job
```

Currently I have been able to put the target tables into the @[User::TargetTables] object variable so that I can loop through them in a for each container.  The current table I want data for is put into the @[User::TargetTable] SSIS Variable.

In my for each container, I am able to pull data from my source that I want for a given target table.

But, I don't know how to put the data into that target table.

How do I insert data into my chosen target table?  (@[User::TargetTable])

```
![DataFlow][1]
![For Each Container Collection Tab][2]
![For Each Container Variable Mapping Tab][3]
![Data Flow Task Container][4]
![OLE DB Destination Object With Error][5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with an OLE DB Destination.

1. Set "Data access mode" to  "Table name or view name variable - fast load"
2. Set the variable name to User::TargetTable